# Подсчитать количество слов каждом предложение

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

Добрый день) Помогите написать программу которая подсчитывает количество слов в  каждом предложение.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char str [80];
    cout << "Enter string:\n";
    cin.getline(str,80);
    int len = strlen(str);
    int i, count = 1, line =1;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){ 
        if (str[i] == ' '){
        count++;
        }
         else 
        if (str[i] == '.'){
            count =0;
            line++;
        }
    }
    cout << "count =" << count << " v " << line << " predlojenie";

    return 0;
```

Вот то что я смогла написать), но оно считает только для последнего предложения.

Comment: Еще бы - вы же сбрасываете счетчик по достижении точки, **не выводя информацию**...

Comment: @Даша Новикова  Как определяется слово? Его границы задаются только пробелами  или также знаками пунктуации?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ну я решила что пробелом, так как после знака пунктуации всеравно следует пробел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас некорректный алгоритм. Вы подсчитываете не число слов, а число пробелов в предложении. Кроме того, введенная строка может содержать несколько предложений, и последнее предложение может не заканчиваться точкой. В этом случае оно просто игнорируется. Кроме того, если следующее предложение начинается сразу же после точки без промежуточного пробела, то опять вы получите неверный результат.

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        const size_t N = 100;
        char s[N];

        std::cout << "\nEnter a sentence (ENter - exit): ";

        if (!std::cin.getline(s, sizeof(s)) || s[0] == '\0') break;

        size_t n = 0;

        for (const char *p = s, *first; *p; )
        {
            while ( *p == ' ' || *p == '\t' ) ++p;

            if (n == 0) first = p;
            ++n;

            while (*p && !(*p == ' ' || *p == '\t' || *p == '.')) ++p;

            if ( *p == '\0' || *p == '.')
            {
                while (*p == '.') ++p;

                std::cout << "\nThere are " << n
                    << " words in the sentence \"";
                std::cout.write( first, p - first )  << "\".\n";

                n = 0;

                std::cout << "\nPress a key to continue ";
                std::cin.get();
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Примерный диалог с программой:

```
Enter a sentence (ENter - exit): One two. Three four five.

There are 2 words in the sentence "One two.".

Press a key to continue

There are 3 words in the sentence "Three four five.".

Press a key to continue

Enter a sentence (ENter - exit):
```

Answer (score 2):

Даша, всецело согласен с коллегами выше))) ... но есть одно "но". Коль ты изучешь не просто Си, а Си++ - начинай учиться правильно. А "правильно" - это использование всех возможностей языка. В том числе и стандартной библиотеки STL. Вот один из вариантов решения поставленной задачи:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

//
// Подсчет слов в предложениях
//

// вынес в using'и просто чтобы немного "разрядить" код, хотя обычно так не делаю
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::pair;    
using std::regex;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::smatch;
using std::regex_match;

typedef vector<pair<string,int>> ResType;

void WordsCount(string T, ResType &Res) {
  smatch Matches;
  regex RegexpDot("^.*?(.+?)\\.\\s*(.*)$"); 
  regex RegexpWord("^.*?([a-zA-Z]+)\\s*(.*)$");     
  vector<string> Lines;  
  while(regex_match(T, Matches, RegexpDot)) { Lines.push_back(Matches[1]);  T=Matches[2]; }
  for(const auto &i:Lines) {
    int N = 0;      
    string Tmp = i;
    while(regex_match(Tmp, Matches, RegexpWord)) { Tmp=Matches[2]; N++; }  
    Res.push_back({i,N});  
  }    
}

int main() {
  try {
    ResType Res;  
    string Text = "mama mila ramu. Rama vusmert' zadolbala mamu. 128 raz.";
    WordsCount(Text,Res);
    for(const auto &i:Res) cout << "\"" << i.first << "\": " << i.second << endl;  
  } catch (std::regex_error& Err) {
    std::cout << "Засада: " << Err.what();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[Вот тут](http://ideone.com/MQAefG) можно посмотреть результат работы. Удачи :)

Comment: Ну вы прямо новичка регуляркой по голове :)

Comment: Один раз испугается, один раз разберется - потом за уши не оттащишь))) Я когда-то так с Perl'ом начинал, так что не с потолка говорю)

Comment: имхо регулярка - перебор. Хватит самописного конечного автомата.

Comment: ну тогда ++ надо убрать из метки, пусть останется "цэ" без плюсов

Answer (score 0):

А если последний цикл сделать таким?

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){ 
    if (str[i] == ' '){
        count++;
    }
     else 
    if (str[i] == '.'){
        cout << "count =" << ++count << " v " << line << " predlojenie";
        count = 0;
        line++;
    }
}
```